# R grepl to find a pure number

Tags: regex, r

Probably a very basic question but its buggging me that i can't easily find a solution...so i thought i should come to the wisdom of the SO wise ones...

I would like to be able to return a TRUE or FALSE acording to if a character string is a pure number rather than just containing numbers... The closest I got was

```
grepl("[0-9]","99393")
grepl("[0-9]","blah")
```

However this doesn't work since the following is returned as TRUE when it should be FALSE

```
grepl("[0-9]","993T3")
```

As ever any help would be appreciated!

*EDIT*

As joran pointed out it is important to note that the character string will only ever include integers and letters, i.e. will not include decimal points or commas for the number...

Comment: For clarity, you should probably edit to specify whether "numbers" here includes things like `3.141` or `54,300`. (I suspect not, but any question involved regex should be precise about these things.)

Comment: Ah good point...regex isnt my forte....and you are right it is only integers and not numerics, and no commas in the string...thanks for noting...the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you just use robust internal methods for coercing to either an integer or numeric?

It will return `NA` if  it can't be done. Use `is.na` if you want a logical result:

```
is.na( as.integer( "993T3" ) )
# [1] TRUE

is.na( as.integer( "99393" ) )
# [1] FALSE
```

Remember that if you are dealing with floating point numbers use `as.numeric` otherwise you will truncate the floating point part of your number using `as.integer`

Comment: What about `as.integer("0xABCD")`?

Comment: @h.l.m is that an edge case we need to be concerned about here?

Comment: @SimonO101 about this edge case...for my current purposes...not really...but I guess to be technically correct, it should probably closer to Matthew Plourde's answer...

Comment: Or check for hexadecimal-ness by matching for this pattern which *must* be at the start of the string: `grepl( "^0x" , x )`

Comment: Why the downvote? The hexadecimal question has been addressed in the comments.

Comment: Another issue: `as.integer("12345678901")`. And another: `as.integer("1e8")`

Comment: `"12345678901"` is outside the representable range of integer values. Why would you ever expect it to be converted? If the OP wants to be able to convert numbers this big then they should not be using `as.integer`. '1e8' this wouldn't deal with. Perhaps the OP should just use regex'ing

Answer (score 11):

You should specify the whole regular expression and specify the beginning (^) and the end of the string ($). For instance :

```
> grepl("^[[:digit:]]+$","993T3")
[1] FALSE
```

Look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing#Regular_Expressions if you want to learn more about regexp.

Comment: This is looking for a one digit string.

Comment: this would pass on the empty string, you want '+', not '*'

Answer (score 0):

What about `!grepl("[^0-9]","993T3")`?

Edit: This returns `TRUE` for the empty string. To avoid this, use

```
!grepl("[^0-9]", x) & nzchar(x)
```

for a vector `x` of character type.

Comment: The idea was that i should be using the same pattern i.e. `grepl("[0-9]",...) to get the answer...so no...

Comment: @h.l.m, I don't understand this "constraint" you impose, i.e., using the same pattern.